# Testing a new mutter build

Tags: window-manager, mutter, compositing

I am testing out a patch for mutter, and for this purpose built mutter and installed this in `/opt/mutter` on my machine.

Now, I want to test it out, with:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/mutter/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
$ /opt/mutter/bin/mutter --replace
libmutter-Message: 10:26:06.960: Running Mutter (using mutter 43.1) as a Wayland display server
Failed to setup: Could not take control: GDBus.Error:System.Error.EBUSY: Device or resource busy
```

How can I test a new mutter build on my system (which already runs Ubuntu's mutter?)

**OS:** Ubuntu 22.10

**Mutter:** latest in git repo.

**Desktop:** Wayland

### UPDATE 1

Even though I was able to run mutter stand alone in a virtual console, I have not found a way to use a new mutter build with my system's gnome.

The libmutter-11.so appears to be directly linked by the gnome-shell binary (I was under the impression it was a run-time plug-in, but that does not seem to be the case?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the compositor does not work.

Instead, launch it from a virtual console (Alt-F3).

To launch it paired with gnome, shell, do:

```
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland dbus-run-session gnome-session
```

The specification for the session is in:

```
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Shell.desktop
```